# How to make a large list in R without using a loop

Tags: r, list

I have around 500 dataframes with two columns and a varying number of rows (from 10 till 30) in R. I also have a character vector containing the names for the dataframes. I now wish to bundle all these dataframes into a single list so I can refer to these list elements using the dataframe names.
I was thinking to use a loop to loop through the dataframes and add them to the list in each step but I couldn't pull it of.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: `mget(<character vector containing the names>)`, however, you should not create 500 separate data.frames to begin with. Put them into a list when they are created.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames Gregor's answer in this question is a good read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
df_names <- c(    ) # yours dataframes names character vector
lst <- list()

for (i in df_names) {
  lst[i] <- list(get(i))
}
```

Comment: This violates the “without using a loop” requirement.

Comment: Yes, but in the last sentence OP mentioned that he's not using loop only because he doesn't know how to pull data frames.

Answer (score 5):

The following works:

```
df_list = mget(df_names)
```

However, the *real* solution is to not have 500 data.frames in your workspace to begin with: either load/create them immediately inside a list, or have your data in such a format that it’s collated into *one* big data.frame.

Think of variables as things you have to keep in your head at the same time: if there are too many to remember, you have too many. Because how else can you reason about the state of your program, i.e. about its semantics and correctness?